# ICEPDF Applet | Disable "Save-As" button from toolbar

Tags: applet, icepdf

I am using ICEPDF(open source java applet) Applet viewer for my pdf to view in my web
without the use of adobe reader.
Now i want to disable "Save-As" button from the toolbar available at top.
I have extracted jar files and dont know which file to customize. Could any1 help
me on the file to be edited so as to hide the save-as option from my toolbar.
Please.. Thanks - Haan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work on `SwingViewBuilder`. Personally, I did the customization by subclassing it and returning nulls for the things I wanted to disable.

**EDIT**:

`SwingViewBuilder` has many buildXYZ() methods. It is only required to make such a method return null for each button/menu item/toolbar that is not needed. The rest of the code is handling the nulls gracefully and skips over it.

Specifically, for the "Save-As" feature, you need to change/override `buildSaveAsFileButton()` and `buildSaveAsFileMenuItem()`.